# how to know if user upgraded the device or using the app in new device?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

How the app will know if user has new device. Apple rejected the build due to missing restore button, but my question is how will i know when to show restore button to user. Because in app done through itunes account on device,

1st scenario:

1.So, now if user login in app made inapp purchase, that user registered with transaction id on app's api backend.

2. Now, user logged out from app, and made login from different account.

Question: Will that user also subscribed in app because itunes account is same in device.

2nd scenario:

1. if user installed the app on new device.
2. Logged in via same account for whom subscription purchased earlier.
3. when user login, api will tell that user is subscribed already so the exclusive content shown already so what is the purpose of restore button how to use it?

3r scenario:

1. if user installed the app on new device.
2. Logged in via different account not for whom subscription purchased earlier.
3. when user login, api will tell that user is unsubscribed.
4. so, in that case will the user be able to make restore purchase because the itunes account is still same from inapp subscription done earlier.

Please guide. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the IAP guide. Restore button is mandatory. It has nothing to do with new device.

Comment: @Desdenova Ok, thanks, but i want to know the answers what will happen on above scenarios.